# How can I populate/imitate server variables in PHPUnit Test cases using Symfony3?

Tags: phpunit, symfony, request.servervariables, liipfunctionaltestbundle

How can I populate/imitate server variables in PHPUnit Test cases using Symfony3?

I try to create functional tests for my symfony3 application.

I use [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle).

I have a special `$_SERVER` variable which contains the country of the visitor. The behavior of the action strongly depends on it.

I try to populate it in my test case.

Here is the content of the `phpunit.xml.dist` file which is based on [Setting PHP INI settings, Constants and Global Variables in PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="app/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
        <server name="COUNTRY_CODE" value="AT" />
        <server name="HTTP_COUNTRY_CODE" value="AT" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>


$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => "test_login",
    'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => "test_password",
    'HTTP_HOST'     => "phpunit.symfony.dev",
    'REQUEST_URI'   => "/app/setting",
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => "/path/to/docroot/app/web"
));
```

and

```
$this->client->request(
    'GET',
    '/app/profile',
    array(),
    array(),
    array(
        'COUNTRY_CODE'      => "AT",
        'HTTP_COUNTRY_CODE' => "AT",
        'SCRIPT_NAME'       => "thing/thong",
        'HTTP_REFERER'      => '/foo/bar'
    )
);
```

when I get the request in the unittest by `dump($this->client->getRequest());` then I see my variables:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#1009
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#1008
    #parameters: []
  }
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#1093
    #parameters: []
  }
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#1092
    #parameters: []
  }
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#993
    #parameters: array:22 [
      "PHP_AUTH_USER"     => "test_login"
      "PHP_AUTH_PW"       => "test_password"
      "SERVER_NAME"       => "phpunit.symfony.dev"
      "HTTP_HOST"         => "phpunit.symfony.dev"
      "REQUEST_URI"       => "/app/setting"
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT"     => "/path/to/docroot/app/web"
      "COUNTRY_CODE"      => "AT"
      "HTTP_COUNTRY_CODE" => "AT"
      "SCRIPT_NAME"       => "thing/thong"
      "HTTP_REFERER"      => "/foo/bar"

      "SERVER_PORT" => 80
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Symfony BrowserKit"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-us,en;q=0.5"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET" => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "127.0.0.1"
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => ""
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1485369277
      "PATH_INFO" => ""
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
      "QUERY_STRING" => ""
    ]
  }
```

but for some reason, in the action

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    dump($_SERVER);
}
```

the `$_SERVER` variable contains the Shell and Environmental Variables instead:

```
"LESSOPEN"             => "| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
"PROFILEHOME"          => ""
"GNOME_KEYRING_PID"    => ""
"USER"                 => "developer"
"LANGUAGE"             => "en_US"
"UPSTART_INSTANCE"     => ""
"XDG_SEAT"             => "seat0"
"SESSION"              => "sess$58479"
"XDG_SESSION_TYPE"     => "x11"
"SHLVL"                => "2"
"HOME"                 => "/home/developer"
"DESKTOP_SESSION"      => "sess$58479"
"QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON" => "1"
"SHELL_SESSION_ID"     => "78c26972fe6040009409a2bd8748034d"
"GTK_MODULES"          => "gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module"
"XDG_SEAT_PATH"        => "/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
"KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION" => "/Sessions/1"
```

What do I do wrong?
Is there any way to imitate the server variables in command line, using Symfony3 and phpunit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was on a wrong way. I can access the server variables through the `$request` object:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    dump($request->server->get('HTTP_HOST'));
    dump($request->server->get('COUNTRY_CODE'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: thanks for the reminder. I wanted to delete this question, but the system reminded me this isn't a good behavior.
I also couldn't accept it as an answer in the first two days, then I forgot about it.

Comment: In some areas like in the test environment you may need to use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack` instead of Request. It's because when testing with the Client object, the $_SERVER and Request are not available in some parts. More info [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html).